# Custom recent-posts shortcode's thumbnail image not in line with rest of code

Tags: shortcode, post-thumbnails, recent-posts

I'm making a custom recent-posts shortcode and I have a problem with the thumbnail image, it always shows it above everything else (permalink, title, etc...) even though I put it after in the code, is there something in wordpress that forces this behavior ?

Here is the code:

```
function mmx_recent_posts_shortcode($atts, $content = NULL)
{
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        [
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'posts_per_page' => '3'
        ], $atts, 'recent-posts' );

    $query = new WP_Query( $atts );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $output = '<div class="row">';

        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

            $output .= '<div class="col span_4">
                <h4>' . get_the_title() . '</h4>
                <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Lire la suite</a>' . the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', ['class' => 'droplet-img', 'title' => get_the_title()]) . '
            </div>';

        endwhile;

        wp_reset_query();

        return $output ; '</div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode('mmx-recent-posts', 'mmx_recent_posts_shortcode');
```

The css code for *droplet-img*:

```
.droplet-img {
    border-radius: 0 50% 50%;
}
```

and here is a screenshot of how it is right now:

[image: how it looks]

and here of how I want it to be:

[image]

If anybody has any idea how to fix it, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thanks!

Comment: can you put a link where this is entirely visible with its html source?

Comment: There are 3 other bugs in your code, the shortcode won't return anything if no posts are found, which is a bug. It's also calling `wp_reset_query`, which is used to clean up after `query_posts`, use `wp_reset_postdata` instead. Finally, don't pass the arguments into `WP_Query` unmodified, instead create a new array and pick out just the ones you want, then put bounds on them to stop somebody requesting 2000 attachments or 1 million private posts

Answer (score 3):

The problem is:

`the_post_thumbnail()` outputs its content immediately. It's basically like `echo`ing instead of `return`ing.

To fix it, you should be able to just replace

```php
the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', ['class' => 'droplet-img', 'title' => get_the_title()])
```

with

```php
get_the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', ['class' => 'droplet-img', 'title' => get_the_title()])
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody for your help, it helped me go in the correct direction.

Here is my final code:

```
function mmx_recent_posts_shortcode()
{
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'posts_per_page' => 3
    );

    $posts = get_posts( array( $args ) );

    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
            echo '<div class="col span_4 mmx-recent-posts">
                <h4>' . esc_attr( $post->post_title ) . '</h4>
                <a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '">Lire la suite</a>' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'thumbnail', array('class' => 'droplet-img', 'title' => esc_attr( $post->post_title ))) . '
            </div>';
        }
    }
}
```